# Camera permission on Android

Tags: javascript, android, camera

The below given code works perfectly fine on Desktopt, but id does not work in mobile. although, I changed camera settings to ASK FIRST, it still does not ask for permission.
Code is given below:

```
buttonStart.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: true,
     
    });
    h1.textContent = "Hiuhiu";
    console.log("it works");
  } catch (error) {
    h1.textContent = "noooo :(";
  }
});
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For us We had same issue,After adding `cleartexttraffic` in manifest file.
I do not know about latest android.

> ```
> ...
> <application
>     ...
>     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
>     ...>
>     ...
> </application> </manifest>
> ```